# C# - Selecting nested model property using a dynamic name

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, properties, model

I have a variable this will be dynamic.

```
string Property_Name = "Email";
```

I have a model for example.

```
AccountModel Model = new AccountModel();
```

Which has a property called...

```
string Email { get; set;}
```

I want to select a property in the Model using the dynamic name.

```
Model.Property_Name
```

Is this possible ? Thanks

Comment: You are misunderstanding this line of code: `string Property_Name = "Email";`. This is not setting the name of the property to Email, it is creating a property called Property_Name and setting it to the string "Email". Why do you want a dynamic property name?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Please see my edited question, this isnt what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using reflection

```
var value = Model.GetType().GetProperty(Property_Name).GetValue(Model, null);
```

don't forget `using System.Reflection;`